# Inflated number of tests and assertions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest

I just got going with autotesting in Rails. It seems like I have everything correctly set up (as I get red/green growl notifications). But I don't understand the growl notifications.

- I have one single model with two attributes
- I have the following gems (autotest-rails, autotest-growl, autotest-fsevent)
- I have set up the ~/.autotest file (with require 'autotest/fsevent', require 'autotest/growl')

I have one test looking like this:

```
test "my first test" do
  assert true
end
```

What I don't understand:

1. I get two growl windows, why?
2. The first window displays the correct "1 test, 1 assertion", but the second window displays "15 test, 21 assertions". How is this possible?

Comment: did you check if there are other tests? they could have been auto generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, that was it. The scaffolding had generated functional tests that I wasn't aware of. Thank you so much @prusswan for the hint.